# Publishing multiple Endpoints with built-in Java JAX-WS web server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, publish, built-in

So I have 2 implementations, Impl1 and Impl2, of a web service interface class. I would like to publish both under the same domain and port but with different URLS:

http://some.domain.asd/ws1 and http://some.domain.asd/ws2

Apparently, I should be able to create a configuration where I have 2 Endpoints, one for each implementation, bound to a single web server instance.

Note that I am not deploying but using the Java 7 internal publishing mechanism.
I noticed that instead of calling

```
Endpoint.publish(URL, new Implementor());
```

to directly publish a web service, I can call

```
Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new Implementor());
ep.publish(serverContext);
```

to publish the Implementor at a specific serverContext. What exactly is such a serverContext and how do I use it? I noticed that the `publish` method instantiates a `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` class and uses it for publishing purposes. But that is apparently not what I am looking for. Ideally, I would like a solution that resembles something like this:

```
Object serverContext = new Server(URL);
Endpoint impl1 = Endpoint.create(new Impl1());
Endpoint impl2 = Endpoint.create(new Impl2());
impl1.publish(serverContext);
impl2.publish(serverContext);
```

Can this even be done with the built-in publishing system, maybe using `EndpointReferences` objects? Or am I required to use a web service container to deploy my Endpoints seperately?

Answer (score 3):

Publishing multiple Endpoints running on the same port could be achieved with this code :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/ws/send", new SendServiceImpl());
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/ws/send23", new SendServiceImpl());
  } 
}
```

Running this locally in Eclipse it works , but when you deploy it to another server its broken.
To fix this you can either use http://0.0.0.0:8888 instead of localhost or the correct internal ip-address of the server.

You find it running:
windows: ipconfig
unix:    ifconfig

It looks something like this: 192.168.100.55.

Comment: If you think the question you link to answer this one too, flag it as a duplicate, do not link it as an answer.

Comment: I can't mark it as duplicate because of my low rep.

Comment: It is no duplicate and the answer woudl have been unsatisfying. But I edited the answer because I found a solution that works well.

Comment: Not working for me even in Eclipse.  The exception is "java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

Comment: @Jian Chen then you should change the port from 8888 to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this problem today; I kept getting "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" when publishing two different endpoints to the same host+port. The solution is to instantiate the `HttpServer` yourself and "bind" each endpoint to this server:

```
package mypackage;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"), 8080), 16);

    final Endpoint fooEndpoint = Endpoint.create(new FooImpl());
    fooEndpoint.publish(httpServer.createContext("/Foo"));

    final Endpoint barEndpoint = Endpoint.create(new BarImpl());
    barEndpoint.publish(httpServer.createContext("/Bar"));

    httpServer.start();
}
```

Comment: I get error "class sun.net.httpserver.HttpContextImpl is not a supported context." at runtime for the publish function.